# Stock Chart and Line char in same plot

Tags: matlab, charts, linegraph, candlestick-chart

I have try to combined stock chart and line graph using **excel**. But it cannot do. I can draw Stock chart and line graph separately. Is anyone know a way to darw stock chart and line chart in same plot. X axis is same. 
If you can do this using Matlab, it also okay.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can plot in MATLAB.

To have a candlestick plot and a line plot of closing prices in the same chart,

```
candle(HighPrices, LowPrices, ClosePrices, OpenPrices)
hold on
plot(ClosePrices)
```

HighPrices, LowPrices, ClosePrices, OpenPrices are all columns. The `hold on` command is to let you plot multiple graphs in the same figure.

`candle` is for making stock-charts and `plot` by default makes line charts.

Refer to the MATLAB documentation on the MathWorks website for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Combining a stock chart and line graph using Excel without VBA is not possible:

[image: SO24585292 example]

Comment: Mmmm, then can we do this using Matlab?